# Unix shell script to find all the matching email ids from in a file A from file B and replace the same with username

Tags: javascript, linux, shell, unix

I have two files A and B. A contains email Id of user and B contains both mail ID and username. I require to read file A and match the file B to find the same mail ids and replace the mail id in A with corresponding username in B.

Thanks

Comment: This site isn't for getting free code, it's for fixing/finding errors in already created code. Please try something before posting. TL;DR: "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas!"

Comment: Please provide the input formats and expected output formats and the script you have tried. :)

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, or at least post what you have tried so far (code)/what you're trying to do (be more specific). This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.